# Waiting for a command to return in a bash script

Tags: bash

What I am trying to do:

My bash shell script contains a `modprobe -a $modulename`. Sometimes loading that module fails and the `modprobe` statement just gets stuck. It never returns and hence, my script is stuck too.

What I want to do is this: Call `modprobe -a $modulename` , wait for 20 secs and if the command does not return and script remains stuck for 20 secs, call that a failure and exit !

I am looking at possible options for that. I know `timeout` is one, which will allow me to timeout after certain time. So I am thinking :

`timeout -t 10 modprobe -a $modulename

   if [ "$?" -gt 0 ]; then

     echo "error"

     exit

   fi`

But the problem is $? can be > 0 , not just because of timeout, but because of an error while loading the module too and I want to handle the two cases differently.

Any ideas using timeout and without using timeout are welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to timeout(1), timeout exits with a specific code (124 in my case) if the command times out. It's highly unlikely that modprobe would exit with that code, so you could probably check specifically for that by changing your condition:

...

RET="$?"; if [[ "$RET" = "124" ]]; then echo timeout; OTHER COMMAND; elif [[ "$RET" -gt 0 ]]; then echo error; exit; fi

BTW, it is a *very* good practice to assign "$?" to a variable immediately after your command. You will avoid a lot of grief later...

If you really do need to make sure, you can check the modprobe source code to see what exit codes it produces, since apparently it was not deemed important enough to mention in its manual page...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Here's what I did:   `timeout -14 2 grep -r 'abc' /` Now I can check for SIGALRM, as I am hoping it is unlikely modprobe will exit with SIGALRM.

Comment: For me, `timeout` exits with 128 plus the signal number. This is actually a feature of Bash. From `man bash`: "The  return  value  of a simple command is its exit status, or 128+n if the command is terminated by signal n." I get similar behavior from other shells.

Answer (score 0):

consider using "expect", you can set a timeout as well as running different command depending on the outcome of the modprobe.

Regards,
Andrew.